# Show next select element if the previous one have an option selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not very practical with jQuery/Javascript, I know how to do it if I specific manually every ID but I know that it's not a good approach to use.

I'm searching for a way, fully dynamic in jQuery, that if a select element (initially with an empty value) have an option selected (value not empty), it show the next select with the same class.

Ex.

That's the HTML:

```
<div id="sel1" class="sel" style="display: block;">
    <select id="select1">
        <option selected value>Default Option</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="sel2" class="sel">
    <select id="select2">
        <option selected value>Default Option</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="sel3" class="sel">
    <select id="select3">
        <option selected value>Default Option</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And that's the CSS:

```
.sel {
    display: none;
}
```

1. So, basically the page start with the first sel1 displayed.
2. If I select an option that have a value not empty (ex. Option1) it show me automatically the next div with class sel (id=sel2).
3. If I select an option not empty in the sel2, it show me automatically the next div with class sel (id=sel3)
4. If I select an option not empty in the sel3 it stop because there's no next div with class sel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like so:

```js
$('select[id^=select]').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).val().length > 0) {
        $(this).closest('div.sel').next('div.sel').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

```css
.sel {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sel1" class="sel" style="display: block;">
    <select id="select1">
        <option selected value>Default Option</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="sel2" class="sel">
    <select id="select2">
        <option selected value>Default Option</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="sel3" class="sel">
    <select id="select3">
        <option selected value>Default Option</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, great approach. One question: is better to use closest or parent? I think in this case, the parent function is more appropriated.

Comment: @Keaire I used closest cause how ever you change your markup (HTML) it will / should always work. But doesn't really make a difference. They're both fast.

Answer (score 1):

This would be it:

```js
$('select').on('change', function(){
      
  var nxt = $(this).parent('div').next(), // next element (div)
      opt = $(this).val();
  
  console.log( opt );
  
  if( opt != '' ){

      nxt.removeClass('sel');

  } else {
  
      nxt.addClass('sel');
  
  }

});
```

```css
.sel {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sel1" class="sel" style="display: block;">
    <select id="select1">
        <option selected value>Default Option</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="sel2" class="sel">
    <select id="select2">
        <option selected value>Default Option</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="sel3" class="sel">
    <select id="select3">
        <option selected value>Default Option</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```